# How to wait when method is finished?

Tags: java, android

I have code bellow. Please, would you tell me how to wait if I call getSpeechInput(); (bottom of the code) while TextView is filled and then call again getSpeechInput(). I tried Thread.sleep, but it doesn't work. 
Thank you.

```js
package com.example.oco.test1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import static java.lang.Thread.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txvResult;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txvResult);
    }
    public void getSpeechInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your Device Dont Support Speech Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 10:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    txvResult.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    public void getSTT(View view) {
       getSpeechInput();
       Thread.sleep(5000);
        getSpeechInput();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are launching an activity, so when it's done onActivityResult is fired.  Put anything you want to do after you call getSpeechInput there instead.

Comment: Thank. Anything. I've tried it before. Please any example?